# Make percentage of decimal number

Tags: java, android

Hey guys i have problem making percentege of double number.

```
    double pom = cumulativeProbability(GetZ(baby));

    Log.d("Pom","" + pom);

    double pom1 = round(cumulativeProbability(GetZ(baby)),2);
    Log.d("Pom1", "" + pom1);

    double pom2 = pom1 * 100;

    Log.d("Pom2: ", "" + pom2);
```

Here are logs:

```
   06-05 02:30:04.574  13208-13208/com.bojan.readfromcsv D/Pom﹕ 0.5821510290598115
   06-05 02:30:04.584  13208-13208/com.bojan.readfromcsv D/Pom1﹕ 0.58
   06-05 02:30:04.584  13208-13208/com.bojan.readfromcsv D/Pom2:﹕ 57.99999999999999
```

I want to round this given pom value into two decimals and that i get with this round function:

```
   public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

For final result pom2 I want to have 58 %.... Tnx

Comment: Any reason you are preferring to round by places, rather than just using Math.round(pom2)??

Comment: Just round your last (pom2) double.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
double pom2 = round(pom1 * 100, 0);
```

EDIT:

```
int pom2 = (int) round(pom1 * 100, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you aren't having to write your own round function, so why not use:

```
pom2 = (int) Math.round(pom1 * 100);
```

Comment: yeah man this is also working but pom2 need to be int like Martín Muñoz said...TNX :D

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help:

```
public class t {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      double pom = 0.5821510290598115;
      System.out.println("pom = "+pom);
      double pom1 = Math.round(pom*100)/100.0;
      System.out.println("pom1 = "+pom1);
      System.out.println("pom2 = "+Math.round(pom1*100));
  }
}
```

Which produces:

```
$ java t
pom = 0.5821510290598115
pom1 = 0.58
pom2 = 58
```

If you want to preserve some more digits in pom2, say 2, do this:

`System.out.println("pom2 = "+Math.round(pom1*100*100)/100.0);`